# Kyriakos Mitsotakis anti-German views

Tags: greece

Has newly elected Kyriakos Mitsotakis Prime Minister of Greece expressed any anti-German views? Has he broached the topic at all?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: You probably meant "you won't find many souls"

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: anyway, I have the impression that he avoided the topic, hence the question.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I suspect that he rather meant what he said, but with a sarcastic tone that may not have survived its journey through the ether.

Comment: @phoog: Oh, I see. It might be a weaker case of Poe's law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law) It's difficult to spot irony over the internet.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: nah, it was just a typo. :D

Comment: This question does not show much research on its own.

Answer (score -2):

Mitsotakis' New Democracy is a member of the European Peoples' Party, which makes him a political ally of Merkel's CDU/CSU. But being for and against the current German government isn't the same as being for or against Germany.

Comment: I think that this answer doesn't answer the question whether or not Kyriakos Mitsotakis has Anti-German views.

Comment: @Philipp, he could be a political ally of the German government and strongly anti-German at the same time, but that would require some political twists and turns.

Comment: He *could*. But is he? That's what this question is asking about.